# How to make for loop code block runs faster?

Tags: java, multithreading, api, twitter, twitter4j

This is a `twitter4j` dependency. I am fetching the user's followers' data.

Below code takes nearly **15 seconds** to finish to fetch data of **45 users** data. What can be done to make this code runs faster? or is there any logic should I add my project roughly?

Multithreading? concurrency?

```java
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
int i = 0;
try {

    IDs ids = twitter.getFollowersIDs(-1);// ids

    do {
        for (long id : ids.getIDs()) {
            String location = twitter.showUser(id).getLocation();
            if(location.length() != 0) {
                list.add(location);
                System.out.println(location);
            }
            i++;
        }
    } while (ids.hasNext());

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(i);
return list;
```

Comment: Parallelism might help, yeah. Presumably `twitter.showUser` is a blocking call, so for every user ID you're waiting for the whole round-trip to complete before moving on the next one. Not optimal

Comment: Maybe you can use lookupUsers (https://github.com/Twitter4J/Twitter4J/blob/8376fade8d557896bb9319fb46e39a55b134b166/twitter4j-core/src/main/java/twitter4j/TwitterImpl.java#L989) and run over the result. This could be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple threads to process data simultaneously.

Also, in case that twitter library supports streams, you can use a `parallelStream()` to do that automatically.

Something like:

```java
IDs ids = twitter.getFollowersIDs(-1); // ids

List<String> locations = ids.getIDs().parallelStream()
    .map(twitter::showUser)
    .map(TwitterUserClass::getLocation)
    .filter(location -> location.length() != 0)
    .collect(Collection.asList());
```